# Are my files encrypted in sleep mode?

Tags: suspend, encryption, security, luks

I have a simple questions but can't to seem to find an answer online.
I've installed Ubuntu 20.04 using full disc encryption. At startup, my laptop now asks me for a password to decrypt.

I use suspend mode a lot, for working in the train. My question is simple: when I suspend my laptop, are my files encrypted? (so when my laptop is stolen in sleep mode, am I still safe?)

Thanks

Comment: This is a complicated question because *technically* the answer is "No", but *practically* the answer is "Yes". Once an FDE partition is accessed, the decryption key will be stored in memory. So long as the machine does not lose power, that key remains in memory. However, so long as you have a password on your account (and any external access to the machine, such as SSH), then the odds of a typical hacker getting access to your files is almost zero. All bets are off if a nation-state is targeting your notebook, though.

Comment: @matigo - I’ve just stumbled on this - I think you should convert to an answer as it’s important and well answered!